# Adding two Double.NEGATIVE_INFINTIY objects in Java

Tags: java, double, ieee-754, underflow

Have a look at this snippet in Java:

```
double alpha = alphaFactors.get(0, q);
double beta = betaFactors.get(0, q);
if ((alpha + beta) > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
    initialDistributionStripe.put(new IntWritable(q),
                                  new DoubleWritable(alpha + beta));
}
```

To avoid garbage values, I want to add to the initialDistributionStripe map the sum (alpha + beta) if and only if it is larger than Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, and is not equal to NaN.

I believe what I am doing is correct and I don't need to explicitly check for 'NaN' because according to the IEEE 754 and Java spec, any comparisons against NaN result in false. So if alpha + beta is NaN, then `((alpha + beta) > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)` will be false.

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***So if alpha + beta is NaN, then `((alpha + beta) > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)` will be false***

That's correct.

If you want to be explicit about it, you could add `&& !Double.isNaN(alpha + beta)` (Keep in mind that `alpha + beta != Double.NaN` is **`true`** even though `alpha + beta` is indeed `Double.NaN`).

Comment: Are you to referring to `static public boolean isNaN(double v)` in Double? Creating an object to perform a test on primitives is ugly even if it worked. ;)

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware about the static version of the isNaN. Thanks, updated.

Comment: There is only a static version, so you don't want the `()` after `Double` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly check for NaN anyway with *isNaN()*. Safer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following is clearer even if it does the same thing.

```
if (alpha > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY && beta > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
```

Otherwise your logic appears to be correct.